# How to merge two UPDATE queries into one, different WHERE and SET?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if it's possible to combine these two queries as they do not work separately (one of the two only works). They are

```
$addquery = "UPDATE winners SET mem_name='$addname' WHERE mem_name='$deletename'";
$addresult= mysqli_query($connect, $addquery);
$query = "UPDATE winners INNER JOIN members SET winners.mem_id = members.mem_id
                    WHERE winners.mem_name = members.mem_name";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Can this be done in just one query? Thank you!!!

Comment: You could, but it doesn't really make any sense to do so. _Also, the WHERE clause in your second query really should be an ON clause for it's JOIN._

Comment: @Uueerdo okay thank you so i'll use join. but do you perhaps know why its doesnt work anymore if i put those two queries . when I delete the first or second it works, but together they dont?

Comment: Most db libraries do not allow multiple queries in a single "execute" call.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying you should do it, but judging from the flow of the code you provided, this is how you *could* do it.

```
UPDATE winners w
SET w.mem_name = '$addname'
, w.mem_id = IFNULL(SELECT m.mem_id 
                    FROM members AS m 
                    WHERE m.mem_name = '$addname' 
                    ORDER BY m.mem_id DESC 
                    LIMIT 1
                   , w.mem_id
                   )
WHERE w.mem_name = '$deletename'
;
```

Note, the ORDER BY is technically optional; your question does not state whether mem_name is guaranteed unique in `members`. If it is unique, the order by should not be needed; if it is not, it at least adds some consistency to the expected value retrieved.

If you have control over the database design, I would suggest removing `mem_name` from `winners` altogether. It is/would be redundant data if you were managing the relation primarily by `mem_id` to begin with.

Comment: okay thank you, i''ll try it. if i remove mem name..where would the persons $addname be placed ??? i thought about removing it but then there's no other way where the users name would be placed in winners, since the User has to choose someone from the table winners and replace it with one from the members table.. so thats why i dont know how i would be able to remove the mem_name even though i want to

Comment: Whatever is used to select the member "name" should contain the name and the id; the name for the user to identify, and the id for the actual update. It can help to look at most strings in sql as the "friendly user label" for an id.

Comment: i have this. <select name = "addname">
     <option value = "0">add the name</option>
     <?php 
     while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo ($row2['mem_name'])?>"> etc.. how can that be done then, that it contains the name and id?/ I'm sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: My php/html knowledge is old and weak, you'd probably be better searching for that, or asking a separate question.